# How to compile Smart Contracts using Brownie on RASPBERRY PI 4B?

Tags: brownie, raspberry-pi

I have set up Raspberry Pi with `npm`, `nodejs`, `ganache-cli`, `eth-brownie` (by downloading straight from github), and VS code.

I was able to do `brownie` command - it worked.
I was able to do `brownie init` - it worked.
I previously set up Brownie on my Mac and followed Patrick's video - and I was able to write my simple Smart Contract, compile it, deploy it and interact with it!

However, running `brownie compile` or `brownie console` the program starts executing and prints: `Downloading from solc-bin.ethereum.org/linux-amd64/…`

and then eventually hits:

```
Download binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output.

SolcInstallationError: Download binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output. If this issue persists, you can try to compile from source code using 'solcx.compile_solc('0.8.6')'
```

Comment: Please copy paste the errors and commands you're running and not use screenshots

Comment: Command that I am running: 'brownie compile'.

Program starts executing and prints: 'Downloading from https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/linux-amd64/solc-linux-amd64-v0.8.6+commit.11564f7e'

After the download it crashes with this error message:

'"Download binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output. "'
'SolcInstallationError: Download binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output. If this issue persists, you can try to compile from source code using 'solcx.compile_solc('0.8.6')''

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue, but have you seen these links? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84125/brownie-cannot-install-solc-on-osx
https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/904
https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/1086

Maybe they help?

Comment: basically from my understanding this error means that the binaries that are downloaded from solc-bin.ethereum.org do NOT work on Rasp Pi for some reason. And I have a question now: Can You help me with a way how to install (produce binaries form libraries) from source code EXACTLY? I saw the comments and the official soliditylang.org article, but there is no procedure on steps on how to Install Solc, build libraries and build binaries and put them somewhere. Can You help with this?

Comment: Maybe. If we don’t get an answer here I’ll see if I can bounty the question to get more eyes

Comment: You are awesome! Lets see!

Answer (score 1):

> `Downloading from solc-bin.ethereum.org/linux-amd64/…`

Looking at the output, you can see that `brownie` is attempting to install the `amd64` version of `solc`. The problem is that you are attempting to run an amd64 (The one prevalent on previous generation Macs and modern PCs) binary on an ARM machine (The ones on Raspberry Pis, M1 Macs, and other smaller devices). These are different processor architectures, and they are not always cross-compatible. I can't find any ARM builds online, but you can try building solidity from source using this [guide](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/installing-solidity.html#building-from-source) from the docs (This however may not be feasible on a Raspberry Pi).

Answer (score 0):

If you want solc on Raspberry Pi, do the follow

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

Then reboot Raspberry, and

```
sudo snap install core
sudo snap install solc
```

Reboot Again, and voila, done!

The solc version that will install is the **0.5.2**