# SolcInstallationError: Downloaded binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output

Tags: solc, brownie, py-solc-x

I am attempting to do the 'brownie compile' but each time it processes I am provided with `'SolcInstallation Error' - Downloaded Library would not execute or returned unexpected output.` I have gone through the steps provided for the (.env file and the brownie-config) as well as the steps prior on the exercises provided. I completed the following up to this error for this exercise.

```
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix
cd chainlink-mix
brownie compile
```

The below is the message I am receiving.

```
SolcInstallationError: Downloaded binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output. If this issue persists, you can try to compile from source code using `solcx.compile_solc('0.4.26')`.
```

Comment: Looks like this is the same question as here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102866/how-to-compile-smart-contracts-using-brownie-on-raspberry-pi-4b I've just bountied that question

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are likely running into the same issue, as [How to compile Smart Contracts using Brownie on RASPBERRY PI 4B?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102866/how-to-compile-smart-contracts-using-brownie-on-raspberry-pi-4b?noredirect=1&lq=1) as mentioned in the comment above, your best solution, rather than diving into the rabbit hole of building the compiler from source, is to compile the smart contracts on a different machine (e.g., a notebook/PC).

After that copy them to the machine that has the problem above and then use the compiled byte codes to deploy them. However, this might require some manual interaction with the blockchain or some changes to brownie source code to avoid it trying to recompile your smart contracts.

In any case, if possible, use a machine that is well supported by the development tools, as you are likely to run into some more issues over time.