# Brownie <> SolcInstallationError, I've tried everything I can find -- nothing has worked!

Tags: brownie, solc

Everytime I try `brownie compile` I see this:

```
SolcInstallationError: Downloaded binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output. If this issue persists, you can try to compile from source code using `solcx.compile_solc('0.5.17')`.
```

I can not for the life of me figure out how to fix this error I am getting. I've read so many posts and tried so many things but I can't get it to work.

- I started using Python 3.9 in my virtualenv based on another post saying that is what worked best
- Dozens of various attempts to brew uninstall, brew install various things.
- paired that with brownie 1.19.3 -- that'd didn't help either.
- I've tried pretty much anything you can imagine with solc, and that has
  not helped.
- I've changed my version of solidity several times, no
  luck either.

I've tried so many things to fix this but I can't find an answer!

**Here is the full error that I see in my terminal, and then I've also posted under this my .sol .yaml .py files.**

```
Brownie v1.19.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Downloading from https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/macosx-amd64/solc-macosx-amd64-v0.5.17+commit.d19bba13
100%|█████████████████████████████████████| 30.4M/30.4M [00:27<00:00, 1.09MiB/s]
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/compile.py", line 50, in main
    proj = project.load()
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 780, in load
    return Project(name, project_path)
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 188, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 257, in load
    self._compile(changed, self._compiler_config, False)
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 100, in _compile
    build_json = compiler.compile_and_format(
  File "brownie/project/compiler/__init__.py", line 121, in compile_and_format
    set_solc_version(version)
  File "brownie/project/compiler/solidity.py", line 97, in set_solc_version
    install_solc(version)
  File "brownie/project/compiler/solidity.py", line 105, in install_solc
    solcx.install_solc(version, show_progress=True)
  File "solcx/install.py", line 466, in install_solc
    raise exc
  File "solcx/install.py", line 459, in install_solc
    _validate_installation(version, solcx_binary_path)
  File "solcx/install.py", line 636, in _validate_installation
    raise SolcInstallationError(
SolcInstallationError: Downloaded binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output. If this issue persists, you can try to compile from source code using `solcx.compile_solc('0.5.17')`.
```

**Here is my brownie-config.yaml file (when I type `which solc` into my terminal, this is the path I see)**

```
compiler:
  solc:
    version: 0.5.17
    paths:
      - /opt/homebrew/bin/solc


networks:
  default: polygon-zkevm-testnet
  polygon-zkevm-testnet:
    chainid: 1442
    host: https://rpc.public.zkevm-test.net
    explorer: https://testnet-zkevm.polygonscan.com
    accounts:
      from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
      from_mnemonic: ${MNEMONIC}
```

**Here is my .sol file**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Capped.sol";


contract LoyaltyRewards is ERC20 {
    address public owner;

    constructor() ERC20("LoyaltyToken", "LOYAL") {
        owner = msg.sender;
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10**decimals());
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can mint tokens");
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}
```

**Here is my deploy.py file.**

```
from brownie import LoyaltyRewards, accounts, network, config

def main():
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    print(f"Deploying to {network.show_active()} using account: {dev}")

    # Deploy the LoyaltyRewards smart contract
    loyalty_rewards = LoyaltyRewards.deploy({'from': dev})
    print(f"LoyaltyRewards contract deployed to: {loyalty_rewards.address}")
```

Comment: Have you seen https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103479/solcinstallationerror-downloaded-binary-would-not-execute-or-returned-unexpect or https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/128654/brownie-unable-to-compile-contracts-on-apple-m1-mac? M1 mac support might just be limited :(