# Brownie compile doesnt work in raspberry pi 4 ubuntu

Tags: solidity

here's my code for solidity

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract blockchainDevelopment {}
```

here's the error im getting.

hope you can help me.

[image]

Comment: It is downloading the wrong solc binaries. I'd suggest to report the issue to their repo https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102866/how-to-compile-smart-contracts-using-brownie-on-raspberry-pi-4b